# Table with no primary key due to lots of duplicates, trying to speed up my query to get rid of duplicates etc

Tags: sql-server

I have a table of products from various suppliers all added together, so there are lots of duplicate SKU's (ManuPartNo), there are other elements, Price, Qty etc.  However I want to Choose the Highest Price based on the SKU (ManuPartNo) and also add together all of the Qty's for any matching SKU. I have a working query but was wondering if anyone could suggest how to speed it up, the table I am querying has 1.3 million rows and my query takes about 40 seconds to run.  Its not too slow but I am trying to learn more about optimization and this question is very hard to google so if anyone could give me any tips or point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

Here is the structure of the table I'm querying and my query its self.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AllProductsFromAllDistis](
[ProdName] [varchar](max) NULL,
[ManuPartNo] [varchar](150) NULL,
[Manufacturer] [varchar](150) NULL,
[Price] [decimal](10, 2) NOT NULL,
[Qty] [int] NOT NULL,
[Weight] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
[UpcCode] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Supplier] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

and my query to return only the values with the highest price and to add all qty's of any duplicate sku.

```
SELECT ProdName, ManuPartNo, Price, TotalQty, Weight, UPCCode, Supplier, 
Manufacturer
FROM
(SELECT dbo.AllProductsFromAllDistis. *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ManuPartNo ORDER BY Price ASC) AS RN,
    SUM(Qty) OVER(PARTITION BY ManuPartNo) AS TotalQty
        FROM AllProductsFromAllDistis) AS t
WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY ManuPartNo
```

As I say this works just fine but I am looking for suggestions on speeding it up.

Comment: First rule of optimisation, view and learn how to read, your execution plan.

Comment: It will be difficult to to write efficient sql that must compensate for schema problems. And I'll note that your query returns **lowest** price, not highest. Highest price would require the order to be descending.

Comment: Sorry this is an old query from my test machine, it is using DESC on the correct one. thanks for spotting it though.  I assumed due to the duplicate entries of ManuPartNo and that im choosing the highest price and also totaling the Qty's, that this would never be the fastest query, just wondered if anyone had any tips or other ways of looking at it.

Answer (score 1):

Although you can’t create a primary key due to the duplicates, you can still create a [clustered index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-clustered-indexes?view=sql-server-2017) which does not require uniqueness but will still improve performance of queries that group or join on the indexes columns. E.g:

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_AllProductsFromAllDistis] ON [dbo].[AllProductsFromAllDistis] ([ManuPartNo])
```

Comment: Thanks Brendon for your answer too, I will have a read up on Clustered index's

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you this

```
SELECT t.ProdName, t.ManuPartNo, t.Price, t.TotalQty, t.Weight, t.UPCCode, t.Supplier, 
t.Manufacturer
FROM
(SELECT ProdName,ManuPartNo,Price,Weight,UPCCode,Supplier,Manufacturer
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ManuPartNo ORDER BY Price ASC) AS RN,
    SUM(Qty) OVER(PARTITION BY ManuPartNo) AS TotalQty
        FROM AllProductsFromAllDistis (Nolock) ) AS t
WHERE t.RN = 1
ORDER BY t.ManuPartNo
```

1. Never forget it allways specify all column ( NOT --> Select * From
   TableProduction)
2. If you are using subqueries put "t" in all your columns
3. Never forget it set a (Nolock) ...could cause blocked
4. Use "Execution Plan" in Menu->Query

I hope this can help you a little

Comment: Never recommend NOLOCK without a good reason and without identifying the problems that this can cause. This is not a magic <go faster> mechanism that is free of consequences.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I didnt know about Nolock, just had a read, dont think it will apply as this data isnt accessed by anyone else until it has been stored in a table, but learned something new :) also thanks for pointing out execution plan, i didnt know it existed, I can get around sql but dont know all the utilities and tools that it has to offer, so thankyou also steps 1 and 2 I will put in.

Comment: @SMor I did read about NoLock, thanks for pointing it out, the new query made no difference to the speed.  What is the reason for putting t's in the query  ? is this just to make things clearer ?  also why specify the actual column names instead of select * ?  I take it that that is incase new columns are added.  thanks again guys.

Comment: It's like telling an SQL server that it has to go this way, so that it does not start and order the same ... a little less work to Sql Server .. Then the execution plan is looked for and the cost of the query...Then the execution plan is a longer theme.
*(Nolock) it does not do it fast but it avoids blocking (not 100%) on a very transactional db.

Comment: I used the execution plan on both your modified query and my own, the results for each stage were exactly the same :)  Thanks again for pointing out the tool it will be useful in the future.